How do you solve the separation between common and "not so common" functions in your public interface?
class PictureList {
     void clear();
     void load(json);
     void clearAndLoad(json);
     void draw();
}

in general clear needs to be called just before load.
Creating just clearAndLoad avoids mistakes and forces the two functions to be called each time in the right order consecutively.
But there are exceptions to that rule so clean and load are kept in the interface for their particular cases where only one needs to be called.
This allows you to keep control and work with these exceptions and in case of bugs, you can focus your effort on the use of clean and load (the unusual calls)
This works great but your public API is now confusing. you have redundancy and there is no way to tell what is the standard interface and which is the "expert interface".
Also in programming, we often say "A function should do only one thing", in that case, clearAndLoad breaks that rule but not having it introduce bugs because it's  more error-prone to type clear(); load(json); than clearAndLoad(json);
How do you solve the separation between common and "not so common" functions in your public interface?

Generally speaking: your methods should reflect the actual workflow with its actual consistency constraints.  If you need "special" operations, especially operations that do violate process constraints, that is possibly a sign of insufficient design: namely, either you are testing/intervening at a too high-level (e.g., for an extreme example, unit testing low level functionality via web services that wrap around it), or those processes are legitimate and simply haven't been designed for (maybe they belong to a separate service API, or maybe they should be restricted to specific roles, etc.)...

My understanding is that your PictureList should always support clear and load, and for a specific kind of PictureLists, clear needs to be called before load.
You can implement this by having a base class BasePictureList with all the methods in your PictureList except for clearAndLoad, and have a specific implementation that overrides the load method by calling the parent's clear and load consecutively:
public class BasePictureList {
     void clear() { // };
     void load(json) { // };
     void draw() { // };
}


public class SpecificPictureList extends BasePictureList {
   @Override
   public load(json) {
      super.clear();
      super.load(json);
  }
}



I am inclined to think you are trying to combine two different type of things in a single interface. Type1 -> When clearAndLoad is always called. Type2 -> When only one of them is called. I would think about the difference again and see if it merits 2 different interfaces with the common behaviour (draw) in a Base class.

"A function should do only one thing", the "one thing" is defined by us and we needn't take this definition too literally. The bottom line is the name of the method should convey the intent and the function should not be too big to understand. I would probably not even name the method clearAndLoad(json) and instead call it render(json) abstracting the implementation/sequence of clear and load from the consumer.


